# Can I define a variant type as "some other variant plus a new constructor" without copy-paste spam?

Tags: ocaml

If I have some variant type `foo`:

```ml
type foo =
  | A
  | B of string
```

and I want to create a *new* variant type `bar` that looks exactly like `foo`, but with a new constructor (arbitrarily e.g. `C of float * int`), is there a way to define this without just writing out the full `type bar = A | B of string | C of float * int`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not *directly* possible as is, but it can be achieved by (at least) two means: using modules, and using polymorphic variants.

The difference is that, in the first case, we create two completely different types. Since their constructor's name clash, they have to live in different modules anyways, so we use functors to automate module creation.

In the second case, we create types that *actually overlap*, meaning that the value `` `A `` (polymorphic variant constructors start with `` ` ``) can be typed both as `foo` and as `bar`.

### Polymorphic variant approach

Polymorphic variants are a little more expensive than regular variants. See [the manual](https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/polyvariant.html) for more information. However, in practice, their biggest disadvantage is that they end up being more "loose" than their non-polymorphic counterpart, in the sense that it's easier to write something unintended and have it typecheck anyways, resulting in weird errors later on.

```ml
# type foo = [ `A | `B of string ]
  type bar = [ foo | `C of float * int ];;
type foo = [ `A | `B of string ]
type bar = [ `A | `B of string | `C of float * int ]
```

Note that this is more powerful than just "copy-paste spam", because `foo` is a subtype of `bar`, and because functions using polymorphic variants can be, well, polymorphic in the actual polymorphic variant type:

```ml
# (`A : foo :> bar);; (* this is ok *)
- : bar = `A
# let f = function (* this function is actually polymorphic *)
 | `A -> ""
 | `B x -> x
 | `C _ -> "C";;
val f : [< `A | `B of string | `C of 'a ] -> string = <fun>
# f (`A : foo);; (* ok *)
- : string = ""
# f (`A : bar);; (* ok *)
- : string = ""
#
```

### Module approach

By using [generative functors](https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/generativefunctors.html#start-section), we can create several types distinct types using the same code and, in combination with [extensible variant types](https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/extensiblevariants.html#start-section), we can add variants to these newly created types. Since the new types are really independent on each other, the constructors that share the same name cannot live in the same namespace. Here, they live respectively in `Foo` and in `Bar`.

```ml
module BaseMaker () = struct
  type t = ..
  type t += A | B of string
end

module Foo = BaseMaker ()

module Bar = struct
  include BaseMaker ()
  type t += C of float * int
end
```

Then you can use

```ml
# type foo = Foo.t
  type bar = Bar.t;;
type foo = Foo.t
type bar = Bar.t
# Foo.A;;
- : foo = <extension>
# Bar.A;;
- : bar = <extension>
#
```

However, this requires adding a wildcard pattern when pattern matching.

Comment: for some other technical reasons, I think the functor approach will work best for me personally. thank you so much for the detailed answer!

Comment: @c-x-berger beware that, as mentioned in the end, if you simply try to do `match Foo.A with Foo.A | Foo.B -> ()` it will trigger a warning, which can be quite annoying. Personally, even though it's not what you asked, I would simply do `type bar = Foo of foo | C of float * int`. But if that solutions works well for you, well, good for you!